# How to use SEP in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I can't sep="_" in my code

How can i do.

```
'''python'''
def sequence(num):
    for i in range(1, num+1):
        print(i, sep="_", end=""
sequence()
```

```
num = 6
i want = 1_2_3_4_5_6
but it show = 123456
```

Comment: You are missing the closing parenthesis `)` at the end of your `print()` line, so this code will give you a syntax error.

Comment: It's the 'end' parameter that is used between different invocations of print, not 'sep'.

Answer (score 1):

The `sep` argument in the `print` function is used only when you pass several objects first.

For example:

```
print(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, sep="_")
```

would print:

```
>> 1_2_3_4_5_6
```

As Thierry explains, the `end` parameter would be the one repeated at each iteration in the given code, but that would result in an extra `_` at the end of the string, which is not what's requested.

One way to achieve the requested result would be something like:

```
def sequence(num):
    print(*[x for x in range(1, num+1)], sep='_')
```

Notice the use of `*` in front of the list of numbers, so that they get expanded. In this case, `sep` argument works as expected.